# Grails:gsp reload google chart not displaying

Tags: javascript, grails, reload

I have been asked to add a google chart to our current grails 2.1.0 application. The main gsp (showdata.gsp) loads and works fine, but when the data is refreshed by a javascript function that is repeatedly calling a second gsp (reloadshowdata.gsp) the chart does not display - other reloaded data is refreshed and displayed correctly. Is the apiImport statement not recognised in the second gsp, how can I get the chart to display?

showdetails.gsp -

```
<%@ page import="org.grails.plugins.google.visualization.data.Cell; org.grails.plugins.google.visualization.util.DateUtil" %>
<html>
<head>
 .... 

<r:script disposition='head'>   
 var reload = function()
 return <g:remoteFunction action="reloadshowdetails" controller="monitor" params="[ turbineId: turbineId ]" update="reloadshowdetails"/>}           
 setInterval( reload, 5000 );
</r:script>
<gvisualization:apiImport/>
</head>
<body>
....

gvisualization:gauge elementId="gauge" width="${200}" height="${200}" redFrom="${90}"        redTo="${100}" yellowFrom="${75}" yellowTo="${90}" minorTicks="${5}" columns="${guageColumns}" data="${guageData}" />

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td> 
      <div id="gauge"></div>
 </td></tr>
 </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

reloadshowdetails.gsp -

```
<table>
<tbody> 
...
<gvisualization:gauge elementId="gauge2" width="${200}" height="${200}" redFrom="${90}" redTo="${100}" yellowFrom="${75}" yellowTo="${90}" minorTicks="${5}" columns="${guageColumns}" data="${guageData}" />

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td>
            <div id="gauge2"></div>
     </td></tr>
 </table>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the script that update the chart is not invoked , if i suppose that you have a remote function `reloadData` in your controller that return the chart data , then When you load new chart datas from the server , you have to execute the javascript code that will draw it in your page. try to add a new function (repaint for example)  and call it when on complete load of chart data  :

```
function repaint(guageData){
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('html_chart_id'));
chart.draw(guageData, options);
}

var loadedData = function()
 return <g:remoteFunction action="reloadshowdetails"
 controller="monitor" params="[ turbineId: turbineId ]" update="reloadshowdetails"/>;
repaint(loadedData);
```

where `html_chart_id` is the id of your chart.

Comment: I don't think it is a data issue - data is retrieved on each page using  ${fieldValue(bean: turbineInstance .... and works fine for other fields, I have also used dummy data in the reloadshowdetails gsp  but still no chart.  Anyway, I will try a repaint as you describe